# Ruby: class definition in method body

Tags: ruby

When I run my code I receive the following errors:

```
Card.rb:51: class definition in method body
Card.rb:74: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I checked lines 51 and 74 and all the associated blocks, but I cannot find any errors. It appears as though all `end` statements are in alignment. When I take out the private methods in Card class the error stops, but I am unable to pinpoint exactly what is wrong. I have the correct amount of end statements, why am I receiving a `class definition in method body` error

```
class Card

  attr_reader :suit, :rank

  def initialize(suit, rank)
    @suit = suit
    @rank = rank
  end

  def face_card?
    @rank > 10
  end

  def to_s
    suitName = suitString()
    rankName = rankString()
    rankName " of " + suitName
  end

  private 

  def rankString
    if @rank <= 10
      @rank
    else if @rank == 11
      "Jack"
    else if @rank == 12
      "Queen"
    else if @rank == 13
      "King"
    else
      "Unknown rank"
    end
  end

  def suitString
    if @suit == :spades
      "Spades"
    else if @suit == :clubs
      "Clubs"
    else if @suit == :hearts
      "Hearts"
    else if @suit == :diamonds
      "Diamonds"
    else
      "Unknown Suit"
    end
  end
end

class Deck
  def initialize
    @cards = []
    suits = [:hearts, :diamonds, :spades, :clubs]
    suits.each do |suit|
      12.times do |rank|
        @cards << Card.new(suit, (rank + 1))
      end
    end
  end

  def shuffle
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def draw(n = 1)
    @cards.pop(n)
  end

  def count
    @cards.count
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code should contains `elsif` instead of `else if`, but you can easily use `case` as well.

Example: method with `elsif` properly:

```
def suitString
  if @suit == :spades
    "Spades"
  elsif @suit == :clubs
    "Clubs"
  elsif @suit == :hearts
    "Hearts"
  elsif @suit == :diamonds
    "Diamonds"
  else
    "Unknown Suit"
  end
end
```

And with `case`:

```
def suitString
  result = case @suit
           when :spades then #then is optional
               "Spades"
             when :clubs
               "Clubs"
             when :hearts
               "Hearts"
             when :diamonds
               "Diamonds"
             else
               "Unknown Suit"
           end
  return result #return is optional
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `else if` statements to `elsif`. Use correct Ruby syntax